# cscope menu without recreating the database?

Tags: unix, cscope

I usually create the cscope database with the command,

```
cscope -bqRv
```

But at times, I just want to access the cscope menu usually got by running,

```
cscope -R
```

This needlessly recreates the cscope database, something, I don't always need. Is there anyway to get to the cscope menu without recreating the database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself! It was there on the cscope main page. (under "Using Cscope on large projects") here - http://cscope.sourceforge.net/large_projects.html

After creating the database I can run this,

```
cscope -d
```

and it brings up the cscope menu !!

Comment: Incidentally, this is very useful for doing quick searches on the command line, like `cscope -dL0main`. Arguably, it would be even more useful if instead of 0-9 you could use something more descriptive, like `c` for caller, ...

Answer (score 0):

The man page on Fedora says:

> **cscope** builds  the symbol cross-reference the first time it is
>   used on the source files for the program being browsed. On a subsequent
>   invocation,  cscope  rebuilds  the  cross-reference only if a source file
>   has changed or the list of source files is different. When the
>   cross-reference  is  rebuilt, the data for the unchanged files are copied from
>   the old cross-reference, which makes rebuilding  faster  than  the 
>   initial build.

Maybe if you don't give any parameters, it won't rebuild the database.  Though it does look as though it will check to see if it should, based on any files being changed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply wallky,

Yes, I'm running in Fedora, but just entering 

    cscope

does not bring up the menu.